# Array filter in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have to filter array in typescript.

```
const { movies, message } = useAppSelector(state => state.movies);

//Here movies is array getting from backend
```

Here I have to filter it in typescript.

I have code in javascript.

```
const mathches = movies.filter(movie => {
    const escapeRegExp = (str) => str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), "gi");
    return movie.name.match(regex);
})
```

I can't understand how can define type here.

Here I get some error when I paste it in ts file-

```
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'never'.
Parameter 'movie' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'str' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Please help me to define type here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Movies isn’t resolving right

Comment: What? I  can't understand it.

Comment: [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiAbgSwKYRgXhgbQFAwwDeYAhnKgFwwBEAKgBaowDmATqqbAO6kA2fGgF8ANAWJkK1GgFkQ4GAGkwyFgyjCxhEuSq1F4FtQDKAawCuAmAEkIfUmAAmm8Tqm05bAEbJzEYXgAugDceHigkLAQnGzADFgwAOTsnFCJoeHg0PBcDHHoCQgo6AB0AGbIfFCobAAURWhYAHzE4oQR2ejApAAOqABKqCwAogAePQm10GzU08hgLACUzTDTJRw99sCotQD0OAA6ALQHh4EHuwdEB0IHtQeLBwBUBwDUBwD8ByUHvwB6BwAJAcAD6BXYsES0X6AgBkNEWbRgHVgHBYqFGCTAqG4MEGI3GtS6vQGQzGPSmMTiiyhNBYyARoUIhA4UHMbDA8CQaBKklQJTgXDitTRGMWoSEiMykBAfH5fBALHquXyEHFQA) works for me. Please share code that has the problem you are describing

Comment: I only had to explicitly set type for the `escapeRegExp` parameter but the rest should work

Comment: The problem is in the type in your `state`. You need to fully define the types in your state, otherwise you can just force the type like `useAppSelector(state = > state.movies) as Movie[]`

Comment: Can you give full details.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a type for movies:

```
interface MovieType { name: string }
```

Then change the filter as

```
const mathches = movies.filter((movie:MovieType) => {
    const escapeRegExp = (str: any) => str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), "gi");
    return movie.name.match(regex);
})
```

Edit: as per the question change

You can update movies as follows:

```
const movies = useAppSelector<MovieType[]>(state => state.movies);
```

Comment: Hello, I update my questions. Can you see it again. Please

Comment: Can you see the question again.

Comment: if `movies` is defined as `MovieType[]` then the rest is just inferred

Comment: Not working! Can you update your answer

Comment: @Aneesh, Please help me now.

Comment: Not working now.

Comment: @MohenDerk can you try `const movies = useAppSelector<MovieType[]>(state => state.movies);`

Comment: @MohenDerk or `const movies = useAppSelector((state:MovieType[]) => state.movies);`

Comment: Yes. you have to know that in this line we get a object of two field. One is `movies` and other is `message`. Here movies is array and message is string.

Comment: I want to filter this movies array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244381/discussion-between-aneesh-and-mohen-derk).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using this

```
const movies: Array<{name: string}> = [
  {name: "The great wall"},
  {name: "Moon Knight"},
  {name: "Kong: Skull Island"},
  {name: "Morbius"}
]
```

```
const mathches = movies.filter((movie: any) => {
    const escapeRegExp = (str: any) => str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(search), "gi");
    return movie.name.match(regex);
})
```

Comment: Hello, Can you help me now. I actually updating my questions